What are the mantras that give immense wealth
What are some mantras that give immense wealth ? And what is the difference between deities like Kuber and maa Laxmi . Both of them provide wealth I guess but still there must be some difference what is it?

Do Sri Suktam sadhana with proper initiation and guidance for what you are seeking.
